# Summing part of data frame over identical factor-levels to get rid of abundance in identical levels in data frame

Tags: r

i have this as part of dataset of about 6000 rows:

```
    ÅR    LM        RE   AGE    PA   REC
1 2012 PKORT Stockholm   <19 17973 35508
2 2012 PKORT Stockholm 20-24 31042 63229
3 2012 PKORT Stockholm 25-29 27305 64558
4 2012 PKORT Stockholm 30-34 18256 42726
5 2012 PKORT Stockholm 35-39 13200 32145
6 2012 PKORT Stockholm   40<  9458 24422
7 2012 PKORT Stockholm   40<  6123 16152
```

and i want to sum all the rows for PA and REC where AGE is "40<" to reduce the data frame from an abundance of identical factor levels. 
I have tried aggregate, tapply and also assumed that R understands that both "40<" should be summed when lm-functions are applied.

This seems like a really easy operation, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(AGE == "40<") %>%
   group_by_(.dots = names(df1)[1:3]) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(PA, REC) , sum)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this code only gave a data set containing the sum of both "<40". I want the sum of the "<40"s to be summed inside my data frame. How may i sum the "<40"s inside the data frame?